# What will be the SQL to get the results by applying group by on specific matching string of column value?

Tags: postgresql

What will be the SQL to get the results by applying the group by on a specific matching string of column value?

**Table: results ( this is not the physical table but the result of specific queries )**

```
rname count1 count2
Avg-1  2      2
Avg-1  1      1
Avg-2  2      2
Avg-1  1      1
Zen-3  2      2
Zen/D  2      1
QA/C   3      1
QA/D   2      1
```

**The expected output is:**

```
rname  count1 count2
Avg      6      6
Zen      4      3
QA       5      2
```

*In expected output count1 is sum of all `count1` of `rname` which match the string **'Avg', 'Zen'** and **'QA'** respectively. Same for count2.*

What will be the SQL can you please give me some directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=15457ec01e7ead8356005b48ff5dbbc6)

```
SELECT
    (regexp_split_to_array(rname,'[-/]'))[1],
    SUM(count1) AS count1,
    SUM(count2) AS count2
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

1. `regexp_split_to_array(rname,'[-/]')` splits the `rname` value at the `-` or the `/` character. Taking the first part (`[1]`) gives you `Avg`, `Zen` or `QA`
2. Group hy this result (using the column index `1`)
3. `SUM` up the values

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but my results can have rname value with different pattern like Avg CD/1, so in this case, I need to match only Avg. Your regular expression will make two separate records for Avg and Avg CD.

Comment: So what could be the matching criterion? As I understood, I cannot take a delimiter (or should I just add the space to the delimiter list, then your example works, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=db1f4ca519249ffd773d4038392a860c), I cannot take "first n characters" because n differs as well...

Comment: Yes, space will be fine, I used it by using CASE WHEN and matching the common string, but sum is not updating.

Comment: Can we match strings like 'Avg', 'Zen' and 'QA'? these are common strings and we know that strings will be common.

Comment: Added space solution in my previous comment. But using the strings can work as well using `regexp_match`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=06270b459e9ec4735b53388d0e471d75